# How to exclude the beginning string in regex match

Tags: regex, jmeter

I have a string containing the following variable "nonce=1ff7de7518b9a52080489ecd7629796d&" how to get the value between the equal and the "&" in regular expression, I have tried nonce=(.*?).+?(?=&) the ending part excluded "&" but I could not exclude "nonce="

Note: trying to match the value between "=" and "&" will not work as there are many "=" and "&" characters which will result in more than 1 match, the unique string is "nonce"

here is an example https://regexr.com/48vmd

Comment: What flavor? Use lookbehind or `\K` if you can, else you'll have to use a capturing group and extract the group

Comment: `nonce=([^&]+)` works in Jmeter, you just need to set the template as `$1$`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `nonce=([^&]+)` to match and capture your intended string from group1

Here `nonce=` will match literally and then `([^&]+)` will match all text before `&` and capture in group1.

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uoAPhn/2)**

In case your regex flavor supports `\K` match reset operator, you can use this regex `nonce=\K[^&]+` to have your intended text as full match without requiring any group text capture.

**[Demo without any grouped capture](https://regex101.com/r/uoAPhn/3)**

If you're using Java, you can use this regex which uses look behind and Java supports look behind.

```
(?<=nonce=)[^&]+
```

**[Demo using look behind](https://regex101.com/r/uoAPhn/4)**

Comment: this is not working as the string contains many "=" and "&" according to your solution it returned 10 matches only one of them is the correct one

Comment: nonce=([^&]+) did not work as "nonce=" is still included

Comment: @MohammadGhanim: As you are using Java, you can use this regex `(?<=nonce=)[^&]+` Check my updated answer's last link.

Comment: @MohammadGhanim: Glad I could make my regex work for you. Please consider upvoting my answer if it solved your problem. In case you have any queries further, please feel free to ping me back.

Comment: @MohammadGhanim: Sorry, I meant accepting my answer. See this post for [How accepting answer helps](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Thanks for upvote @Callum. I was indeed wondering as how come OP was able to upvote as he only had 1 rep where as you need minimum 15 rep for upvote.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the regular expression it would be as simple as `nonce=(\w+)&`

Demo (assumes RegExp Tester mode of the [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener)

[image]

Even easier way would be going for [Boundary Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-boundary-extractor-vs-the-regular-expression-extractor-in-jmeter) which basically extracts everything between the given "left" and "right" boundaries:

[image]